# Show that $1$ and $2$ are zeros of the following polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

> Show that $1$ and $2$ are zeros of the polynomial $P(x)=x^4-2x^3+5x^2-16x+12$ and
>    hence that $(x-1)(x-2)$ is a factor of $P(x)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A **zero** of a polynomial is a value of $x$ for which $P(x) = 0$.

To show that $1 \text{ and}\; 2$ are zeros, substitute each value into the polynomial $P(x)$ and evaluate the polynomial to confirm that it evaluates to $0$:

Determine if $P(1) = 0? $ and if $P(2) = 0?$...

That is, what do you get when you let $\;x = 1?\;$ What do you get when you let $\;x = 2$?
If $P(x) = 0$ when $x = 1$, then $x = 1$ is a zero of $P(x)$. And if $P(x) = 0 $ when $x = 2$, then $x = 2$ is a zero of $P(x)$

Note that if $x_0$ is a zero of a polynomial, then $(x - x_0)$ is a ***factor*** of the polynomial.
So once you confirm that $P(1) = P(2) = 0$, you will know that $(x - 1)(x-2)$ is a factor of $P(x)$: when either *factor* evaluates to zero, the entire factored function $P(x)$ evaluates to zero.

***Good to know***: whenever you are given a factored polynomial - suppose you are given that $Q(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ - you can easily "read off" its "zeros".

Recall that anything multiplied by zero is equal to zero.:

So when will $\;\bf Q(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)= 0\;?$

- $Q(x) = 0\;$ when $\;(x - 1) = 0\implies x = 1$,
- $Q(x) = 0\;$ when $\;(x - 2) = 0 \implies x = 2$,
- $Q(x) = 0\;$ when $\;(x - 3) = 0 \implies x = 3$.

  Any of those values for $\,x: x= 1, \,x = 2,\,\text{ or}\; x= 3,\,$ will give you $Q(x) = 0$.

Comment: p(1)=1^4-2(1)^3+5x^2-16(1)+12 = 0    also  p(2) = 0  etc ---

Comment: Exactly! You've just shown that $1, 2$ are zeros.  That means that $(x - 1)$ is a factor, and so is $(x - 2)$ a factor, and so is $(x - 1)(x-2)$!

Comment: You're very welcome!  ;-)

Comment: It is *not true* generally that it $\rm\:a\ne b\:$ are roots of $\rm\:f(x)\:$ then $\rm\:(x-a)(x-b)\mid f(x),\:$ e.g. over $\rm\:R = \Bbb Z_8 = $ integers $\rm\:mod\ 8,\,\ x = 1,3\:$ are roots of $\rm\:x^2\!-1,\:$ but $\rm\:(x\!-\!1)(x\!-\!3)\nmid x^2\!-1\:$ in $\rm\:R[x].\ $ See the [Bifactor Theorem.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/326672/23500)

Comment: If you've learned "synthetic division" or "polynomial division", you can now use this result to find the remaining factor of your polynomial -- since that is a quadratic polynomial, you could then solve for the _other_ two zeroes.

Comment: @amWhy: You have been busy lately! :-) +1

Comment: Hi, Amy. :-) ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Hello, Babak!!!!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $(x-a)$ is a factor of a polynomial $P(x)$, if $P(a) = 0$. Hence, to check if $(x-1)$ and $(x-2)$ are factors, find the value of $P(1)$ and $P(2)$ to conclude what you want.

Answer (score 1):

**The is an application of the [Factor Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem).**

If $\operatorname{f}(x)$ is a polynomial and $\operatorname{f}(p)=0$, then $x-p$ is a factor of $\operatorname{f}(x)$. In particular: if $\operatorname{f}(1)=0$ then $x-1$ is a factor of $\operatorname{f}(x)$ *and* if $\operatorname{f}(2)=0$ then $x-2$ is a factor of $\operatorname{f}(x)$. Hence to show that $\operatorname{f}(x)$ has $(x-1)(x-2)$ as a factor, we must show that both $\operatorname{f}(1)=0$ *and* $\operatorname{f}(2)=0$. Notice that:

\begin{array}{ccccc}
\operatorname{f}(1) &=& 1^4 - 2 \times 1^3 + 5 \times 1^2 - 16 \times 1 +12 &=& 1 - 2 + 5 - 16 + 12 &=& 0 \\
\operatorname{f}(2) &=& 2^4 - 2 \times 2^3 + 5 \times 2^2 - 16 \times 2 +12 &=& 16 - 16 + 20 - 32 + 12 &=& 0
\end{array}

It follows that *both* $x-1$ *and* $x-2$ divide $\operatorname{f}(x)$ and so their product $(x-1)(x-2)$ divides $\operatorname{f}(x)$.

Comment: thanks a lot fly by night for your nice answer ... you are smart .... thanks you for your simple explain

Comment: @MomenOsama You're welcome. I'm sorry it wasn't the best.

Comment: Your answer was one of the best answers and the most organized, thank you and all those who contributed to the success of this great site

Answer (score 0):

You just have to substitute x by 1 and by 2. This will give you $P(1)=0$ and $P(2)=0$ is these values are eventually zeros. If they are, you could factorize them by $(x-1)(x-2)$ because the zeros of this expression are 1 and 2.

Comment: thanks moray95 for you answer